# how to request google to recrawl a url (without Fetch As Google)

Tags: seo, web-crawler, googlebot

I'm working on a website with 15,000 visits per day, we have hired ads on that, some of them are important (they are for banks) and the content of these kinds of ads will never change, but at some point they announced that they need some people with repeated content (Jobs and Requirements never changes :| ). Now we need to tell Googlebot to recrawl those URLs, so we updated the content of the target pages with different writing but Googlebot doesn't crawl them as fast as needed. Using Fetch as Google is an opinion but there are a lot of ads and we need an automatic way do that. What is your advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the way you want to achieve this is not possible, because Google decides how often to recrawl a page based on its popularity, the number of backlinks and how valuable it thinks your page is to its users. You can't force Google to recrawl a page if you don't want to use fetch as Google.

However, there is a workaround. Create a new page with the new content, using a new URL (containing a recent date for example, but the same path otherwise), and have the old page redirect to it with a 301, or set a canonical link from the old page to the new page. This will surely accelerate the indexing of the new page, while removing the old one pretty quickly. It will pass most of the PR juice from the old page to the new page. Make sure the new page is added to your `sitemap.xml` too.

That will achieve what you want automatically (pretty much).

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid automation and submitting links on an ad-hoc basis. Build a clean xml sitemap. An xml file tells search engines that your sitemap may contain dynamism and frequent changes along with a healthy list of URLs. It means that if your Sitemap uses well-formed XML code, supplies clean, valid URLs, and meets the other requirements of the search engines, the URLs it contains will **at least be noted for consideration** by the search engines for future crawling activity. Patience pays off....

A healthy xml sitemap helps sites that use dynamic URLs for their content pages and sites with archived content that’s not well-linked to its currently active pages. Also xml sitemaps assists sites with hard-to-discover pages that use hard-to-crawl links (*such as those in scripts*) or that are heavy in non-text content , such as Flash or Silverlight.

There are a lot of solutions online to help generate an XML sitemap. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your Sitemap you can specify how often content changes. It's not going to guarantee that it crawls that often but it will let Google know that's how often it needs to crawl.

[google help to create Sitemap.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en)

Comment: thank, but we have and sitemap and we don't have a regular period for renew ads, so Googlebot ignored our sitemap :(

Comment: You could use the last modified tag to tip search engines, but there is no guarantee they would take it into account...